# undefined function in angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I was just going through the code of angular-openlayers-directive **[HERE](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/blob/master/src/directives/openlayers.js#L29)** , now i see alot of checks like below:

```
if (isDefined(attrs.width)) {
```

now `isDefined` is obviously a function and `attrs.width` is the parameter being passed, But where is this function `isDefined` defined and most importantly how can i find it ?

Comment: You have it in here [link](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/blob/ead5fe5ba8ef998a1e526fb849a69bd8b06cff10/src/services/olHelpers.js)

Comment: Here is a link to [Angular Documentarion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `isDefined` is injected into the directive as part of the `olHelpers` service.

You can find it in `angularjs-openlayers-directive > src > services > olHelpers.js`